# Scalar subquery produced more than one element - bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have 2 tables
1 that records searches done by users and 1 for product categories

I'd like to retrieve the most common searches keywords and see if it matches current categories and how often categories appear in searches

Table 1  (searches)

| search_id | search_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone 6 with case |
| 2 | desks for big monitor |
| 3 | laptop case walmart |
| 4 | laptop case |
| 5 | iPhone 6 |
| 6 | laptop monitor |
| 7 | iPhone 7 with case |
| 8 | iPhone 6 |
| 8 | tv monitor |

Table 2 (categories)

| category_id | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone |
| 2 | monitor |
| 3 | laptop |

```
WITH AS serach_results
(
Select search_name, count(*) from searches
 group by search_name
  having count(*) >=3
).

select count (category_name), category_name
    from categories
    where regexp_contains(category_name), (select search_name from serach_results))
```

I expect something like this

| f_ | category_name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | iPhone |
| 2 | monitor |
| 4 | laptop |

I get this error
Scalar subquery produced more than one element
I understand the BQ logic behind this error but how can I get the expected result by BQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below approach

```
with search_results as (
  Select search_name, count(*) cnt from searches
  group by search_name
  -- having count(*) >=3
)
select sum(if(regexp_contains(search_name, category_name), cnt, 0)), category_name
from search_results, categories
group by category_name
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]